# Axios get method and rendering flatlist

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist

I am new to the react native and I have used the following code to show the users list using axios. I am not getting error but the list is not showing. I think the mistake is in rendering the  FlatList but I can't seem to figure out the error.
Any help would be  really appreciated.

```jsx
const UserslistPage = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  const getUsers = async (event) => {
    console.log("calling");
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(`${baseUrl}/api/users`)
      .then(async (res) => {
        setUsers(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log("success");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("failed");
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.bigcontainer}>
      <View style={styles.title}>
        <Text style={styles.titletext}>USERS LIST</Text>
      </View>

      <FlatList
        data={getUsers}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => "key" + index}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return <UsersList item={item} />;
        }}
      ></FlatList>
    </View>
  );
};
```

The code for `<UsersList/>` that's in the Flatlist is :
**
UsersList.js **

```jsx
const UsersList = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.userslist}>
        <View style={styles.user}>
          <Text style={styles.user_name}>{item.username}</Text>

          <Text style={styles.user_status}>{item.roles}</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.3} style={styles.bttn}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Delete</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I am not getting any error but still getting an empty list can anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: I think you meant to use `data={users}`. `getUsers` is your function whereas `users` is your state (data)

Comment: @Phil actually, It worked . I was using data={users} before but it was not working  now it's working fine  lol.  Thank you !!!